# Facebook email is returned as undefined from phonegap facebookConnect plugin

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am using the phonegap [facebook Connect plugin](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin) to enable facebook login in my app. 
However the facebook email is being returned as undefined.

Do I need to add something into my code?
I have looked up this issue on the internet and it seems my code should work. Everything else is returned except for the email address.

I would appreciate if you can help

Here is my javascript code:

```
   facebookConnectPlugin.api('/me?fields=id, email, link, name, picture', ["public_profile"],function(data){
        var fb_user_id = data.id;
        var fb_email = data.email;
        var fb_name = data.name;
        var fb_picture_url = data.picture.data.url;
        var fb_user_link = data.link;
        alert("fb_email" + fb_email);
    }); //end api call
```

Edit:

I tried a test user account with this code and the email address DID get returned. However for the real account I was testing with this doesn't work.

With more testing I tried adding in the email permission as follows however this did not work as the data that I got back stated "FACEBOOK_NON_JSON_RESULT"

```
 facebookConnectPlugin.api('/me?fields=id, email, link, name, picture', ["public_profile", "email"],function(data){
            var fb_user_id = data.id;
            var fb_email = data.email;
            var fb_name = data.name;
            var fb_picture_url = data.picture.data.url;
            var fb_user_link = data.link;
            alert("fb_email" + fb_email);
        }); //end api call
```

Comment: You probably require to add `email` to the scope permissions ? Not all fields are available.

Comment: @Searching thanks. actually i've tried this code with a test user account and test facebook app (instead of a real facebook account and real app) and the email Does* get returned. So it was just happening with a real account. I will update this question with any new findings.

Comment: @Searching as you can see (in my edit) i added in the email permission but got bad data back... I've now done a separate request with email permission which works. thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a workaround for this problem which was to do two separate api requests as follows:

```
    facebookConnectPlugin.api('/me?fields=email', ["email"], function(apiResponse) {

            //alert("api" + JSON.stringify(apiResponse));
            fb_email = apiResponse.email;
            alert("fb_email" +fb_email); //email being retrieved successfully
            facebookConnectPlugin.api('/me?fields=id, name, link, picture', ["public_profile"],function(data) {
                 alert("data" + JSON.stringify(data));

                 var fb_user_id = data.id;
                 var fb_name = data.name;
                 var fb_picture_url = data.picture.data.url;
                 var fb_user_link = data.link;

                 alert("fb_user_id" + fb_user_id);          
                 alert("fb_name" + fb_name);
                 alert("fb_picture_url" + fb_picture_url);
                 alert("fb_user_link" + fb_user_link);
                 //do stuff with facebook user data here
             }

             ,function(error){  
                   //api call failed
                   alert("api call Failed: " + JSON.stringify(error));
             }); //end api                          
   }

   ,function(error){    

            alert("email api call Failed: " + JSON.stringify(error));
   }); //end api
```

This works perfect!